# Find closest city to given location

Tags: c#, gps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I am trying to find the closest city to given location. I have stored location of some cities that I want to work with. And I have my location, but I dont know how to find the closest city to my location ?

```
Cities
New York - Lat 40.714353; Long -74.005973
Washington - Lat 38.895112; Long -77.036366
....more cities

My location
Philadephia - Lat 39.952335; Long -75.163789
```

So how should I compare the coords to find the closest city ? I am doing program in C# but just knowing the solution of algorythm is enaught for me :)
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use your high school knowledge to solve this problem, your alghorithm is:

closest = sqrt ( (lat2 - lat1) ^2 + (Long2-Long1) ^2 )
now this give you your air distance.

so, when you do this for an array of values, you can use asort function to compare which one is closest to you.

Comment: This is not quite right. At 40°N, a degree of Latitude is a longer distance than a degree of Longitude. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude#Length_of_a_degree_of_longitude

Comment: @EeroAaltonen my answer (or rather, one of the alternatives I give) deals with that, but this can be close enough for some purposes, and is faster to compute. My only objection would be the needless `sqrt`, which isn't going to affect relative ordering.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly, you'd want to use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

However, while you could perhaps be just slightly out in far northern or far southern points, you could probably get by by pretending that Mercator projections are accurate for distance, and ignoring the curvature of the earth. This is especially true if you are going to have lots of cities, as the error is greater, the further points are from the target point. Hence you would just use Pythagoras':

```
relDist = √((xLat - yLat) × (xLat - yLat) + (xLng - yLng) × (xLng - yLng))
```

But since you only care about (and only get) a relative ordering, you can skip the square-root bit, which is the heaviest step:

```
relDist = (xLat - yLat) × (xLat - yLat) + (xLng - yLng) × (xLng - yLng)
```

As well as being faster in and of itself, it can also be reasonably preformed on integers, should you store your coordinates as multiples of the actual coordinate (e.g. storing New York's (40.664167, -73.938611) as the pair (406642, -739386). This can be a big boost if you want to quickly sort a large number of places in order of proximity to a given point.

If however you really care about precision in the face of the fact that the earth is round, then the following implements Haversine:

```
private const double radiusE = 6378135; // Equatorial radius
private const double radiusP = 6356750; // Polar radius
private const double radianConv = 180 / Math.PI;
public static double GetDistanceBetweenPoints(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2)
{
  double dLat = (lat2 - lat1) / radianConv;
  double dLong = (long2 - long1) / radianConv;
  double a = Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2) + Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Sin(dLong/2) * Math.Sin(dLong/2);
  return Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(radiusE * radiusP * Math.Cos(lat1 / radianConv), 2)) / (Math.Pow(radiusE * Math.Cos(lat1 / radianConv), 2) + Math.Pow(radiusP * Math.Sin(lat1 / radianConv), 2))) * (2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The distance bitween two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) is

```
d = sqrt((x1 - x2) ^ 2 + (y1 - y2) ^ 2)
```

so in c# you we will have:

```
public City FindNearestCity(double currentLatitude, double currentLogitude, List<City> cities)
{
    Dictionary<City, double> distances = new Dictionary<City, double>();
    foreach (City city in cities)
    {
        double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(city.latitude - currentLatitude, 2)  + Math.Pow(city.Longitude - currentLogitude, 2));
        distances.Add(city, distance);
    }
    double minimumDistance = distances.Min(distance => distance.Value);
    return distances.First(distance => distance.Value == minimumDistance).Key;
}
```

Comment: Why bother with the `Math.Sqrt`? The results are still going to be in the same order without it.

Comment: @Jon Hanna you are right. But with sqrt it is easier to name variables:)

Answer (score 0):

Visit [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Closest-pair_problem#C.23) 
you can find two c# function using Brute force and divide-and-conquer algorithms to find the closest two points among a set of given points in two dimensions.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question in any way though.

Answer (score 0):

Jon's answer is very inspiring, although there're few missing pieces.

- lat1 should be in a 
  `double a = Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2) + Math.Cos(lat1/ RadianConv) *  Math.Cos(lat2/ RadianConv) * Math.Sin(dLong / 2) * Math.Sin(dLong / 2);`
- The simulated radius in last statement gave 2000ish sometimes, which should be close to either RadiusE or RadiusP, so I used mean radius instead.
  `return 6371* (2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a)));`